# Is there a risk of namespace collision of two constants, if used in imported modules but declared outside of them?

Tags: javascript

If I have three files, basically something like this:

file_one.js:

```
const lol = () => {
    console.log('Laughing out loud in file_one')
}

const funcOne = () => {
    lol()
}

export default funcOne
```

file_two.js:

```
const lol = () => {
    console.log('Laughing out loud in file_two')
}

const funcTwo = () => {
    lol()
}

export default funcTwo
```

one_and_two_importer.js:

```
import funcOne from 'file_one'
import funcTwo from 'file_two'


funcOne()
funcTwo()
```

My assumption was that the function lol would be in global scope and thus cause a namespace collision, but apparently that doesn't happen. Also, if I try to log the function lol in one_and_two_importer.js, I get undefined error.

As the [documentation says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), import inserts the module to the current scope, but in which scope are the constants that are used by the imported modules?

Comment: The two modules have their own scope, if you look at the transpiled code in Babel you will see that the `lol` function is namespaced automatically to avoid collisions.

Comment: @FezVrasta what about native import (non transpiled code)?

Comment: Same thing, but managed by the JS engine.

Comment: Also, unless you export lol directly and then import it with the same name twice, there shouldn't be a conflict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two `lol` functions are now [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), which means that although they still get called inside each of the `funcOne` and `funcTwo` functions, they are hidden in the sense that they are not publicly accessible.

With ES6 modules (or commonJS for that matter), the only names that get injected into the local namespace are the names that you explicitly import, eg in all the cases

```
import x from 'y'
import { x } from 'y'
import * as x from 'y'
```

The namespace will only get the additional variable of `x`. No other variables get injected in a hidden manner.

The only way that you *would* get a clash is if you were to export the `lol` variable explicitly in both files and then try to import it by its name. Eg having in both files

```
export lol
```

and then

```
import { lol } from 'file_one'
import { lol } from 'file_two'
```

Unless you try to do something like this, the two `lol` variables would be scoped to their respective modules and so wouldn't conflict with each other.

I'd recommend reading more about [how closures work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) in JavaScript.

Comment: When you say "variables would be scoped to their respective modules" does that mean in this case they would be somehow transferred inside of the funcOne/funcTwo? I have understanding how closures work, but in this case I have hard time understanding what happens "under the hood".

Comment: What happens is each `lol` variable is separate, enclosed in their own modules. They do not clash because JS doesn't internally think of them as `lol` variables, they're just two different variables contained inside two different modules. Does that help explain it? If you try and pinpoint exactly what you're struggling with I can try and come up with a specific example to illustrate what happens.

Comment: I am afraid there is something fundamental I don't understand/know about modules, so I do my homework first and come back to this if needed.